# HangMan Game in C problem in word to show

Tags: c

I'm working on hangman game in c and Im doing the part where the user chose a letter and knows if it is rigth or not

So, I have this 2 functions to hide all the characters and reveal the characters if the user get it right:

```
void hideAllCharacters(char * palavra){
    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(palavra); i++){
        palavra[i] = '*';
    }
}

int revealCharacters(char * palavra, char * palavraEscondida, char caracterInserido){
    int result = -1;

    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(palavra); i++){
        if(palavra[i] == caracterInserido){
            result = 1;
            palavraEscondida[i] = palavra[i];
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

and then here's tthe part of the code where I determine if the user wins when he got all the letters right:

```
do{
    printf("\nLetra: ");
    scanf(" %c", &letra);
    descobriu = revealCharacters(palavra, palavraEscondida, letra);
    if(descobriu == -1){
        printf("\nA palavra não tem o caracter ´%c´\n", letra);
        perde++;
        enforcado(perde);
    }else{
        enforcado(perde);
        ganha++;
    }
    printf("\nENCODED = %s\n", palavraEscondida);


}while((perde!= 6) && (ganha != 4));
```

And my problem is, I'm using 4 letter word's, and when the word have equal letters the game will continue when the hole word is complete, this happen because of my variable `ganha` but I dont know how to solve, any sugestions?

Comment: So after guessing 4 letters ganha is supposed to be 4 and the do while is supposed to exit? Did you try printing ganha to see what the value actually is after guessing 4 ?

Comment: You would need to post a complete example for someone to be able to run your code. As it is now there are functions missing, and we can't see the variable initialization which may be wrong.

Comment: when the 4 letters are different the programm will exit and there are no problems, but when the word have 2 equal letters ganha will only be equal to 3 and the program will continue to run with the word guesses because ganha have to be equal 4, and I dont know how to exit if there are equal letters on the word

Comment: OK now I understand. You need to change your design. One easy way is to have revealCharacters return the total number of matches instead of always returning 1 if there is a match.

Comment: You can change    if(palavra[i] == caracterInserido){             result = 1; to          if(palavra[i] == caracterInserido){  result++ }  and change ganha++ to ganha = ganha + descobriu

Comment: And what can I do to the condition on while? because ganha is always equal to 0 now

Comment: It should not be. I just gave you an idea, not the final solution. There are other changes you need to make like chaning int result = -1; to int result = 0; and others. I'm sure you will be able to figure it out on your own.

Comment: Im here just to say that we did it, thank you so much for the help!!

Comment: Great job! I'm glad I could help.

Comment: "ganha" is never initialized. At least, not in the code you made available to us. Even if it works now, it might fail in the future when "ganha" will happen to start from another value.